# Mp3Play module won't run on OS X

Tags: python

I have successfully installed `mp3play` module with `pip`, but when I try to run the code below on OS X - macOS Sierra:

```
import mp3play

f = mp3play.load("button_click.mp3")

def play_sound():
    f.play()
play_sound()
```

I get the following message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/Larisa/PycharmProjects/KvizMatura/main.py", line 9, in
>   
>       import mp3play   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mp3play/**init**.py",
>   line 6, in 
>       raise Exception("mp3play can't run on your operating system.") Exception: mp3play can't run on your operating system.

Why can't `mp3play` run on a mac? What could I use instead? I like this module because it is very easy to use and clean to read. Is there any way I can use it on my operating system?

Comment: So you downloaded this module without even reading its description, which starts with "Allows your Windows Python program to play and stop MP3s"???

Comment: Yes, I have seen someone else use it and didn't know it was only for Windows.. I have also tried using modules Pyglet and Sound with no success.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this library to play sounds:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["afplay", "button_click.mp3"])
```

I don't like it because it is very slow and apparently only works for OS X.